# android create groups in recyclerview from arraylist

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of objects where each object contains its position coordinate (Lat, Long) like below,

```
    ArrayList<Person> friends = new ArrayList<Person>();
    Person person = new Person("Alex",42.387310,-101.423977);
    friends.add(person );
```

I am showing list in `RecyclerView`, which is working fine, but I need to show this list in groups. For example if there is list of 10 people and two of them are close to each other like then make a group of those two.

I can find distance from their **lat**-**long** but i dont know how to make a group from that distance. I also need a unique background color for each group i.e. when distance between two or more people is less than 50 Meter than make a group of that object and render that  item with that background color

**Current Adapter**

```
      public   class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
           private ArrayList<NearMe> mDataset;

           public  class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
               View mView;
               public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                   super(itemView);
                   mView = itemView;
                   FrameLayout group_countx = (FrameLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.count_badge);
                   group_countx.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               }

               public void setTitle(String title) {
                   String output = title.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + title.substring(1);
                   TextView post_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                   post_title.setText(output);
               }

           }
           public MyAdapter(ArrayList<NearMe> myDataset) {
               mDataset = myDataset;
           }
           @Override
           public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
               View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                       .inflate(R.layout.contact_row, parent, false);
               return new MyViewHolder(view);
           }
           @Override
           public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {



                 Double Latitude = mDataset.get(position).getLatitude();
                 Double Longitude = mDataset.get(position).getLongitude();


                 holder.setTitle(mDataset.get(position).getName());



               holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               });

           }
           @Override
           public int getItemCount() {
               return mDataset.size();
           }
       }
```

**Output example**

[image]

**Edit 2** i have created a method which is adding same background if they are closer but this is also adding color to individuals rows

**my function**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < nearByFriends.size(); i++) {
            String groupID = "group_"+i;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
            NearMe f1 = nearByFriends.get(i);
            for (int ii = 0; ii < nearByFriends.size(); ii++) {
                    NearMe f2 = nearByFriends.get(ii);
                    Double d = SharedHelper.distance(f1.getLatitude(), f1.getLongitude(),f2.getLatitude(), f2.getLongitude(), 'K');
                    if(d <=  0.1) {
                        nearByFriends.get(i).setColor(color);
                        nearByFriends.get(ii).setColor(color);
                        nearByFriends.get(i).setNearby(true);
                        nearByFriends.get(ii).setNearby(true);
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the definition of `NearMe`?

Comment: NearMe is a object which contains a person name , latitude, longitude

Comment: If `List<NearMe>` has 10 objects and 2 of those `Person`s are candidates of forming a group then how many rows be displayed (9 or 11)?

Comment: if list has 10 objects its will show 10 rows but if two or more  object are closer then they  those rows have different background for example to  show them as group

Answer (score 0):

If you can calculate the distance, then i would suggest adding color as another parameter for nearme object before sending it to the recycler view.

**Look at the following example, it should put you in the direction.**

This is how you can make group of persons based on their distances.
You can save a list of colors in Values folder and use a different color for every new group.

```
class person {
    Integer distance;
    String color;

    public person(Integer distance, String distance) {
        this.distance= distance;
        this.color = color;
    }




List<person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    personList.add(new person(5, ""));
    personList.add(new person(10, ""));
    personList.add(new person(25, ""));
    personList.add(new person(28, ""));
    personList.add(new person(52, ""));
    personList.add(new person(80, ""));
    personList.add(new person(90, ""));
    personList.add(new person(120, ""));
    personList.add(new person(150, ""));
    personList.add(new person(1030, ""));

    for (int i = 0; i < personList.size(); i++) {
        person personOne = personList.get(i);
        for (int j = i + 1; j < personList.size(); j++) {
            person personTwo = personList.get(j);
            if (personOne.distance- personTwo.distance< 5 && personOne.distance- personTwo.distance> -5) {
                personTwo.color = "black";
                personOne.color = "black";
            }
        }
    }
}
```